# GoldenGate for SQL Server does not create extract files

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I installed GOLDENGATE for SQL Server database two weeks ago. Everything was OK until yesterday.

I noticed my target database (Oracle 12c) tables not actual.

Then I check GoldenGate logs `ggserr.log` file, there was nothing like error or abnormal.

I run `'info all'` at GoldenGate CMD, extracts and pumps is running. But there is no new extract files-trails in `\dirdat` path.

I try restart all extract and pump processes and manager but there is still no change. But `Lag at Checkpoint` times shows 30 hours.

What can be the problem? Or where can I check to know problem?

Comment: "Everything was OK until yesterday.". So, what changed *yesterday*?

Comment: I am sure nothing changed.

Comment: I I've experienced this case before. I restart all extracts and problem solved. But now 'restart' can not resolve

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CDC capture?  If so, make sure the SQL Server CDC job is running.

You don't say which trail is missing.  Local or Remote?

Check the data from the source to the destination.
To troubleshoot:
1. stop the extract/pump/replicat
2. Make a change on the source
3. See if that change gets written the the CDC table
4. Start the extrac
5. Do a stats extract and see if the change was picked up
6. Make sure the change is in the local extract files
7. start the pump
8. Do a stats pump and make sure the change is being picked up by the pump
9. make sure the change is in the remote trail
10. start the replicat
11. do a stats replicat and see if it is picking up the change